# Cohomology of realization space of matroid

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, matroid-theory

Do we know any thing about cohomology of realization space of matroid (the space of all set of vectors in $\mathbb{C}^k$ which captures the independence structure of matroid $M$), more simple, for uniform matroid $U_{k,n}$? The realization space is totally determined by structure of matroid, so as the cohomology, can we write it? I found little paper about this thing, does people lost the interest to calculate it since the realization space can be vary complicated by Mnev's universal theorem?

Comment: Small comment: $U_{k,n}$ is usually represented as $n$ points general position in $\mathbb{C}^k$, even though you write $\mathbb{C}^n$. Maybe you have a different convention about what $k$ vs. $n$ means. (I would imagine this space, because of its "general position" nature, has not so bad cohomology compared to arbitrary matroid varieties, but don't know for sure.)

Comment: @SamHopkins, thanks for your comment, it's a typo, it's $\mathbb{C}^k$